# Laravel 4 - Pattern matching between Routing and Controller function

Tags: php, controller, routes, laravel

With CodeIgniter you can do something like this:

```
route['foo/(:any)'] = 'controller/$1';
```

This way, you create a pattern matching, using the last part of the URI as a function name for the controller.
So, 'foo/bar' will be routed to the controller 'controller' and the function executed will be 'bar'.

***Question:*** can I do the same with **Laravel 4**? I've searched all over the place but couldn't find an answer. Tried to test it following CI's idea but had no success. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RESTful controllers with this very simple syntax :

```
Route::controller('foo', 'FooController');
```

Then you will be able to use routes like that in `FooController` :

```
// GET /foo/clients/2
public function getClients($id)

// POST /foo/vip-clients
public function postVipClients()
```

Documentation : http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers